# AngularJS how to format an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am working on an app that read an excel file and upload its contents to a ui.grid.
That part is working good.
I need to also create a second array with the same data but a different purpose, to use on a 3rd party api call.

The array needs to have this format:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "frank",
      "email": "frank@email.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "mike",
      "email": "mike@email.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

currently my array looks like:

```
data: Array(5)
    0:
        Email: "janderson@email.com"
        Name: "Jack Anderson"
    1:
        Email: "ejohnson@email.com"
        Name: "Ed Johnson"
    2:
        Email: "dpoole@email.com"
        Name: "Dead Poole"
    3:
        Email: "hschmidt@email.com"
        Name: "Hank  Schmidt"
    4:
        Email: "salves@email.com"
        Name: "Steven Alves"
```

The code I am using:

```
$scope.arr = new Array;

// SEND THE FILES.
$http(request)
    .then(function (data) {

        angular.forEach(data.data, function (item) {
            var b = {
                Name: item.Name,
                Email: item.Email
            };

            $scope.arr.push(b);
        });

    }).error(function (error) { });
}
$scope.gridData = { data: 'arr' };
```

How can I change the code, or add code, to create an array that meets the format I need?

Thank you for your help.
Erasmo

**UPDATE**

This is my code after adding the recommendation

```
.controller('myController', function ($http) {

    var formdata = new FormData();
    var vm = this;

    vm.getTheFiles = function ($files) {
        angular.forEach($files, function (value, key) {
            formdata.append(key, value);
        });
    };

    // SEND FILES TO THE API USING POST METHOD.
    vm.uploadFiles = function () {

        var request = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/fileupload/',
            data: formdata,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': undefined
            }, transformRequest: angular.identity
        };

        vm.arr = new Array;

        // SEND THE FILES.
        $http(request).then(function (data) {

                angular.forEach(data.data, function (item) {
                    var b = {
                        name: item.Name,
                        email: item.Email
                    };

                    vm.arr.push(b);
                });
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
        });

        var items = vm.arr.map((item) => {
            return {
                name: item.name,
                email: item.email
            };
        });

        var panelists = {
            "panelists": items
        }
        console.log(panelists);

    }

    vm.gridData = { data: 'arr' };
```

Comment: Does your application support `ES6` ?

Comment: Not sure how to answer, I am using a web api/mvc solution with c# programming language, and front end angularjs.

Comment: Why are people still injecting $scope into their controllers when Google recommended against doing this 7 years ago? Look up how to use controller As syntax and components.

Comment: @Adrian Brand - I did the search you suggested and also made some changes to my code accordingly. I updated the code above. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your loop, you can use `Array.map()` to rename the keys of your array objects to all lowercase, then you can place that array in a new object as the "users" property:

```
var foo = $scope.arr.map((item) => {
    return {
        name: item.name;
        email: item.email;
    };
});

var bar = {
    "users": foo
}
```

Of course, rename these variables to more accurately reflect their purpose.

If you need to only provide the first name, you need to split the string at the space:

```
item.name.split(' ')[0];
```

Another approach to consider is renaming the properties `Email` and `Name` to `email` and `name` in your original loop so that the format is the same and you can reuse the same array. If this object is being passed to a grid that is set up to look for the capitalized names, you may need to reconfigure it to accommodate this change. This would look something like:

```
angular.forEach(data.data, function (item) {
    var b = {
        name: item.Name,
        email: item.Email
    };

    $scope.arr.push(b);
});
```

And in whatever call you need to make to the third-party endpoint, you can add this array on the fly in a similar way:

```
someThing.doThing({
    "users": $scope.arr;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using old version of angular. So I use vanilla JavaScript

You can create a function `$scope.getGridData` just to transform your data to your desired output

```
$scope.arr = [];

// function that transforms your response data to gridData

$scope.getGridData = function(data) {
  if (!data) {
    return [];
  }
  var returnData = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
    returnData.push({ name: data[i].Name, email: data[i].Email });
  }

  return { users: returnData };
};


// Your http request
$http(request).then(function(data) {
  // your current array
  $scope.arr = data.data;

  // your transformed grid data is assigned to gridData
  $scope.gridData = $scope.getGridData(data.data);
}).error(function (error) { });
```

You need to assign values to `$scope.arr` and `$scope.gridData` inside `then` block because the `data` is not available until http request is resolved.

So now you have `$scope.arr` which as your current array.

And you have `$scope.gridData` which has your transformed data

Comment: let me give this a try.